# Positioning images in Graphics using Inset

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I need to position a certain part of a photographic image at the origin of a plot in Graphics. I am currently using `Inset[image, {0,0}, {xpos,ypos}, size]` and varying xpos and ypos until it looks right. This is time consuming considering the number of images I am adding. Is there a way to select the desired point on each image and then obtain its coordinates within that image so that I can determine xpos and ypos exactly. Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Maybe setting `Axis->True` so that you can determin the position on one glimps.

Comment: You might want to use `Raster`. Unlike Inset, it uses standard graphics coordinates and makes it possible to align an image with other graphics elements with perfect precision.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but it can probably done using [`LocatorPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html) and Dynamic, e.g. like this:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "CarAndAPC"}];

pt = {0, 0};
Row[{
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], img], 
  Dynamic[Plot[Sinc[x], {x, -10, 10}, 
          Prolog -> {Inset[img, {0, 0}, pt]}, ImageSize -> 300]], 
  Dynamic[pt]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I need, nikie. I will also try Szabolcs' suggestion to use Raster for greater precision with the alignment.  This was very helpful.